# Adding string list item to int array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, int

Hello I need to take string item from string list and a add it to the int array i trying like this but its writing me error Cannot implicity convert type int to int[]
but in for sequence i adding only one int to one item in array so what is wrong please

```
private void buttonGenerateO_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            List<string> AgentNumbers = new List<string>();
            List<string> AgentRide = new List<string>();
            int pocet = AgentNumbers.Count;
            int[][] dvouRozmernePole = new int[2][];
            dvouRozmernePole[0] = new int[pocet];
            dvouRozmernePole[1] = new int[pocet];

        foreach (string AgeNumb in AgentNumbers)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dvouRozmernePole[0].Length; i++)
                dvouRozmernePole[i] = Convert.ToInt32(AgeNumb);

        }

        foreach (string AgeRide in AgentRide)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dvouRozmernePole[1].Length; i++)
                dvouRozmernePole[i] = Convert.ToInt32(AgeRide);

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dvouRozmernePole` is an array of `int[]`, while `Convert.ToInt32` returns an `int`. Therefore in:

```
dvouRozmernePole[i] = Convert.ToInt32(AgeNumb);
```

`dvouRozmernePole[i]` is an `int[]`, and you are trying to assign an `int`.

It looks like you want:

```
dvouRozmernePole[0][i] = Convert.ToInt32(AgeNumb);
```

and later

```
dvouRozmernePole[1][i] = Convert.ToInt32(AgeRide);
```

You could instead do:

```
int[][] dvouRozmernePole = new int[2][]
{
    AgentNumbers.Select(num => Convert.ToInt32(num)).ToArray(),
    AgentRide.Select(ride => Convert.ToInt32(ride)).ToArray()
};
```

to initialise the array.

Comment: Ok im quite a noob so how can i add items from list to array ? Im googling for 3 hours and this is a result but now im stacked... how can i fill the array ?

Comment: @user1936559 - There are a few ways, one is a loop similar to what you have, another is to use LINQ. I've added a LINQ example.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this declaration:

```
int[][] dvouRozmernePole = new int[2][];
```

So `dvouRozmernePole` is an *array of arrays*. Now look here:

```
dvouRozmernePole[i] = Convert.ToInt32(AgeNumb);
```

You're trying to assign an `int` value to `dvouRozmernePole[i]`, which you can't do because it should be an `int[]`.

I suspect you want:

```
dvouRozmernePole[0][i] = Convert.ToInt32(AgeNumb);
```

Having said that, given these lines:

```
List<string> AgentNumbers = new List<string>();
List<string> AgentRide = new List<string>();
int pocet = AgentNumbers.Count;
int[][] dvouRozmernePole = new int[2][];
dvouRozmernePole[0] = new int[pocet];
dvouRozmernePole[1] = new int[pocet];
```

... you'll always have empty lists anyway, so there are no values to convert.

Do you *really* need to use arrays at all? Using `List<T>` everywhere would almost certainly be simpler.

LINQ can also make this simpler. For example:

```
int[] numbers = AgentNumbers.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
int[] rides = AgentRide.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
int[][] dvouRozmernePole = { numbers, rides };
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear. In the statement

```
dvouRozmernePole[i] = Convert.ToInt32(AgeNumb);
```

you assign an integer to an array.

Answer (score 0):

dvouRozmernePole is an array of array of ints

so `dvouRozmernePole[i]` expects and int[] rather than the int value

try

did you mean

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dvouRozmernePole[0].Length; i++)
           dvouRozmernePole[0][i] = Convert.ToInt32(AgeNumb);
    }

    foreach (string AgeRide in AgentRide)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dvouRozmernePole[1].Length; i++)
            dvouRozmernePole[1][i] = Convert.ToInt32(AgeRide);

    }
```